# Sorting and Grouping in Pandas data frame column alphabetically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I want to sort and group by a pandas data frame column alphabetically.

```
          a    b      c
0     sales    2    NaN
1  purchase  130  230.0
2  purchase   10   20.0
3     sales  122  245.0
4  purchase  103  320.0
```

I want to sort column "a" such that it is in alphabetical order and is  grouped as well i.e., the output is as follows:

```
          a    b      c
1  purchase  130  230.0
2             10   20.0
4            103  320.0
0     sales    2    NaN
3            122  245.0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `df.sort_values(by='a')`? Where is the need to group them?

Comment: Oh yeah! sorting alone would be fine. Thanks :)

Comment: @RRK The visual effect of column `a` won't happen like that.  But @JohnGalt's answer will get it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the `sort_values` method of `pandas` :

```
result = dataframe.sort_values('a')
```

It will sort your dataframe by the column `a` and it will be grouped either because of the sorting. See ya !